# Executar .bat por um botão

Tags: php

Como posso executar um .bat na pasta do site por um botão? Pode ser feito isso em outras linguagens também se não for possível só por PHP

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Executar .bat</button>
```

Comment: Novamente repito o que disse na pergunta duplicata que você deletou, isso seria um grande risco de segurança, isso se for possivel, afinal, php não executa nada na maquina de quem ta abrindo o site, já que ele roda no servidor apenas.

Comment: veja isso: http://www.somacon.com/p395.php

Comment: Queria que executasse no mesmo Articuno, no caso estou utilizando uma VPS

Comment: Bem perigoso isso. Não o faça de animo leve e sem saber os riscos que corre

Comment: @Articuno Depende do .bat a ser executado. Se esse link aparecer em página protegida visível apenas para administradores e esse .bat for algo para reiniciar o servidor, fazer um backup ou realizar alguma outra tarefa administrativa, isso faria todo o sentido.

Comment: Sim, é para isto @Victor Stafusa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No PHP, você pode usar a função [**`shell_exec`**](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.shell-exec.php):

```
<?php
    $output = shell_exec('seu-arquivo.bat');
    echo "<pre>$output</pre>";
?>
```

É importante porém antes de tudo, certificar-se da segurança disso, garantindo que não seja possível que qualquer usuário execute qualquer script.

Comment: 2 perguntas, como posso fazer essa ação funcionar quando apertar no botão? E o bat precisa estar na pasta onde está localizada a index?

Comment: @BetaDarkNight Você põe isso em uma página que responda a algum tipo de POST. O script não precisa estar na mesma pasta do index e inclusive, devido a questões de segurança, é muito melhor que ele não esteja lá, e nesse caso você usaria `shell_exec('C:\\alguma-pasta\\seu-arquivo.bat')`

Comment: Tem como iniciar um programa exe só que com tela? Pois mostra no gerenciador de tarefas que está funcionando mas está sem a tela

Comment: @BetaDarkNight Executar um .exe ao invés de um .bat deve funcionar também.

Comment: Ele executa o .exe, porém a página só fica carregando e não mostra os logs. Porque será?

Comment: @BetaDarkNight O .exe executou até o fim ou ele apenas foi iniciado e ficou lá rodando?

Comment: Ficou rodando, que é para isso acontecer, ele é um CMD que tem informações quando inicia, queria que mostrasse essas informações, mas ele fica rodando

Comment: @BetaDarkNight O problema é que essa função espera o processo terminar. Se não deveria ser esse o caso, você poderia usar [essa outra função](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.exec.php), mas provavelmente ainda não vai dar certo. O melhor que você tem a fazer é usar `shell_exec('start C:\\alguma-pasta\\seu-arquivo.exe > C:\\alguma-pasta\\saida.txt')`, e colocar uma outra página PHP que lê o arquivo `C:\alguma-pasta\saida.txt` e o coloca na requisição (que nessa outra seria GET).

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68144/discussion-between-betadarknight-and-victor-stafusa).